# Cascade deletion in Django models with GenericForeignKey

Tags: django-models, cascading-deletes

I have the following problem with Django.

```
class UserProfile(Model):
    inventory = models.M2M(InventoryItem)

class InventoryItem(Model):
    item = GenericForeignKey()

class Equipment(Model):
    base = GenericForeignKey()
```

Every user can have many items. Inventory item can point to equipment, materials and so on, but in this case it points to Equipment model. Equipment model has a relation to either Weapon or Armour or Accessory.

I need to remove a specific item from user's inventory.

```
UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1).inventory.objects.all()[0].delete()
```

** This also deletes equipment and weapon/armour/accessory objects related which is not intended. **

I have already added on_delete=DO_NOTHING on all foreign keys, but I do not see such option possible on GenericForeignKeys. What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1).delete()

it looks like you're deleting the UserProfile, but not the specific item

Comment: ooops, I didn't mean to write that.